# Call a function within AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple function which shows a success div on a success of something:

```
anysuccess("The user has been removed from this list.");
```

This shows a DIV at the top of the page.

I want to call this after an AJAX call e.g.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ajax/actions/remove_user_from_list.php?sei=' + sei + '&sui=' + sui,
            success: function (data) {
                if(data==='ok'){
                    anysuccess("The user has been removed from this list.");
                } else {
                    $('#errorBoxEvent').html('Houston, we have a problem!');
                }
            }
        }); // End .ajax
```

When I try this I get `anysuccess is not defined` which I'm guessing is a scope issue?

Is there a way to call functions within ajax response? Or a workaround?

Comment: how is your anysuccess function defined?

Comment: Make sure it's defined before you execute that AJAX call, it should work fine. Can you provide more information like a source code?

Comment: change place of `anysuccess` function after or before ajax

Answer (score 0):

It works fine

May be when you check the success condition it will not goes to the "if" part

```
            if(data){
                anysuccess("The user has been removed from this list.");
            } else {
                $('#errorBoxEvent').html('Houston, we have a problem!');
            }
```

[check this on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wbeeq/)